# Write multiple rows on Google Sheet (at once) with data from a dictionary (using Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script

On app script, I have a dictionary object with the format: { name1: "info1", name2: "info2", …  }.

Screenshot of the sheet for reference: [gsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmOec.png) (didn't link the actual sheet because there's nothing much on it)

Edited: How would i write the apps script code to fill up column B at once? Meaning, I would not have to call the same function for each row! I can just call the function once and column B would be filled.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `How would i write the apps script code to fill up the "Information" column all at the same time (i.e. write multiple rows, and not 1 row at a time)?`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: @Tanaike Hello, just edited my question — hope it makes more sense now!!

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted, and also the discussions have already been advanced. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer and discussions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function myFunction() {
  // building the dictionary
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  const dict = `{ "name1": "info1", "name2": "info2", "name3": "info3"}`
  // parsing the dictionary
  const obj = JSON.parse(dict)
  const values = sh.getRange('A2:A'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().map(k => obj[k] || 'not found')
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,2,values.length,1).setValues(transpose([values]))
}
function transpose(a){
  return Object.keys(a[0]).map(function (c) { return a.map(function (r) { return r[c]; }); });
}
```

[image]

Comment: hello! thanks so much for the help :) Wanted to ask if would it be possible to just write/fill column B? So — the Name column would already be filled.

(but this function defo works,,)

Comment: done, let me know if everything is ok

Comment: thank you! Another question for ya while i try the new function out: is it possible to avoid converting the dictionary into a const string then an array? What's the reason for doing so (sorry, i'm new at apps script and JS)

Comment: no need to go through a string ... how is your dictionnary? as an array? can you give how it is built?

Comment: ahh sorry then what are the ' ' around the dictionary? Not completely sure what u mean but the dictionary was just built by iterating through the rows from another spreadsheet (key = customer name, value = transaction history). I just wrote: dict={ } to initiate, then dict[name]="…transaction details…" to add to the dictionary.

Comment: I have edited my answer to use `dict`, then you can omit the two first rows of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
  const dict = ...
  const data = Object.keys(dict).map(key => [key, dict[key]])
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                .getSheetByName(`MY_SHEET`)
                .getRange(2, 1, data.length, data[0].length)
                .setValues(data)
```